# Why does PhpStorm ask me "password for ssh key git" when I try to push a commit?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh, ide, phpstorm

I am pretty desperate. I am using **PhpStorm** as PHP IDE. It is derived from **IntelliJ** and I am experiencing a very strange problem with GIT.

Each time that I am trying to push a commit on my GIT repository I get this popup asking to me the **password for ssh key git**:

[image]

On IntelliJ I have no problem. I am not so into Git... what is this SSH key?
I think that it should be the content of this file: **`C:\Users\Andrea\.ssh\id_rsa`** (or something like this).

It seems to me that I have generated this on my GIT server (but maybe I am doing wrong assertion).

Anyway...why IntelliJ have no problem (the server is the same) and PhpStorm is creating me this problem?

Comment: It is asking for the passphrase of your private key, because you apparently have entered a passphrase when you first created the key, and therefore need to enter the passphrase when attempting to use the key.

Comment: @1615903 ok...but where hae I to retrieve it? And why IntelliJ doesn't ask me?

Comment: In IntelliJ you have most likely entered the passphrase once and selected 'Remember me' option.

Comment: And you don't "retrieve it" from anywhere, it's a passphrase that you have manually entered when creating the key.

Comment: Please always state your IDE versions (for both PhpStorm and IntelliJ) as well as OS used (must be Windows here as far as I can see).

Comment: @LazyOne I am using Windows 8.1 PhpStormn 2016.3.2 (trial version). Intellij 2016.2

Comment: @1615903 and if I don't remember it? How can I rebotain it?

Comment: 2016.3 has new way of storing passwords -- it will be KeePass db on Windows and choice of OS keyring or KeePass on Mac/Linux (check what you have there at `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords`). Your one could be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162522 (*rather a wild guess from my end*) or some another from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=keepass

Comment: If you don't remember it, create a new key.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot retrieve the passphrase from IntelliJ `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords` (considering that, 4 months later, [IDEA-162522](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162522) is still unresolved), the easiest workaround is to:

- recreate a new one

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "comment" -q -P "" -f newKey
  ```

(Note: ssh-keygen is available on Windows, under `<git>\usr\bin\ssh-keygen.exe`)

- register its public key in the Git remote hosting service you are using that key to authenticate yourself (GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab, ...).